# lighttpd url.rewrite-once += (...) erasing earlier rules?

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

In my lighttpd.conf:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(www\.|foo\.|bar\.)?domain\.com$" {
    url.rewrite-once += (
        "^/favicon.ico$"        => "/images/favicon_cd.ico",
        "^/course/?$"           => "/course/index.php",
        "^/course/([^./]+)$"    => "/course/index.php?w=$1"
    )   
}
...
# don't allow spiders to crawl subdomains
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(foo\.|bar\.)?domain\.com$" {
   url.rewrite-once += (
       "^/robots.txt$"          => "/robots_nocrawl.txt"
   )
}
```

We have `www.domain.com` as well as `foo.domain.com` and `bar.domain.com` for specific clients. And plain `domain.com` should work too.

The first set of rewrite rules send `.../course/x` to `.../course/index.php?w=x`. Those work for `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`, but for `foo.domain.com` and `bar.domain.com` the rewrite doesn't work. I can see the rewrite is not happening by turning on lighttpd's debug logging.

If I disable the second block of `rewrite-once` rules that just try to prevent robots crawling `foo.domain.com` and `bar.domain.com` the first set of rewrites will work for all subdomains.

I am pretty sure `url.rewrite-once += (...)` works because I have an earlier set of global rewrite-once rules that are applied.

Any idea why the last set of rewrite-once rules that are only supposed to be applied to foo and bar subdomains would prevent the earlier rules working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(www\.)?domain\.com$" {
    url.rewrite-once += (
        "^/favicon.ico$"        => "/images/favicon_cd.ico",
        "^/course/?$"           => "/course/index.php",
        "^/course/([^./]+)$"    => "/course/index.php?w=$1"
    )   
}

# don't allow spiders to crawl subdomains
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(foo\.|bar\.)?domain\.com$" {
   url.rewrite-once += (
        "^/favicon.ico$"        => "/images/favicon_cd.ico",
        "^/course/?$"           => "/course/index.php",
        "^/course/([^./]+)$"    => "/course/index.php?w=$1",
        "^/robots.txt$"         => "/robots_nocrawl.txt"
   )
}
```

I don't think Lighttpd like having multiple rule for the same matches, I mean `foo.` & `bar.` matche more than one regex in your case. Here, there is only one that can matche.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd configuration is parsed at startup.  The *results* are matched per request, but the configuration rules are static after startup.  In other words, you can not combine `+=` across different conditions where some conditions may match some requests, and other conditions may match other requests.

Instead, you can store your shared rules in a variable and reuse the variable.

```
var.shared_rewrite_rules = (
        "^/favicon.ico$"        => "/images/favicon_cd.ico",
        "^/course/?$"           => "/course/index.php",
        "^/course/([^./]+)$"    => "/course/index.php?w=$1"
)

$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(www\.)?domain\.com$" {
    url.rewrite-once += var.shared_rewrite_rules
}

# don't allow spiders to crawl subdomains
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(foo\.|bar\.)?domain\.com$" {
   url.rewrite-once += var.shared_rewrite_rules
   url.rewrite-once += (
        "^/robots.txt$"         => "/robots_nocrawl.txt"
   )
}
```

In your specific case, an alternative to the above is to simply use `url.alias` to direct "/robots.txt" to an different filesystem path, instead of duplicating the rewrite rules.